# Need help on MySQL query, i need to get the starting balance and the end balance by date group by stock_id

Tags: mysql

I need to get the starting balance from the earliest date and the ending balance from month end and group by stock_id.
My table:

```
id    stock_id   balance     transact_at
1     1          100         2018-06-15
2     1          70          2018-06-16
3     1          30          2018-06-31
4     2          50          2018-06-01
5     2          10          2018-03-31
```

I want output:

```
stock_id start_balance    ending_balance
1        100              30   
2        50               10
```

Comment: Great.  Have you tried something yet?

Comment: select
(select balance from my_table order by id limit 1) as start_balance,
(select balance from my_table  order by id DESC limit 1) as ending_balance
from my_table 
group by stock_id but didnt get the right result

Comment: Your expected output looks wrong to me.  For `stock_id` #2 the _earlier_ balance is 10, and the _later_ balance is 50.  Also, June does not have 31 days, it only has 30 days.

Answer (score 1):

One approach in MySQL would be to aggregate by `stock_id` once and find the opening and closing dates.  Then, self-join twice to pull in the actual balances which occurred on those opening and closing dates.

```
SELECT
    t1.stock_id,
    t2.balance AS start_balance,
    t3.balance AS ending_balance
FROM
(
    SELECT
        stock_id,
        MIN(transact_at) AS min_transact_at,
        MAX(transact_at) AS max_transact_at
    FROM my_table
    GROUP BY stock_id
) t1
INNER JOIN my_table t2
    ON t1.stock_id = t2.stock_id AND t2.transact_at = t1.min_transact_at
INNER JOIN my_table t3
    ON t1.stock_id = t3.stock_id AND t3.transact_at = t1.max_transact_at;
```

[image]

### Demo

Note: For posterity's sake, when MySQL 8+ becomes the norm, we could make use of things like `ROW_NUMBER` here, which might make it easier to get the result we want.

Comment: Nope, it should get the start balance from the earliest date and the ending balance as the month ends. That query will only get the min and max balance

Comment: Your expected output and data do not convey this requirement.  If you expect another query, then update your question with data.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Nice one. Even my query is giving the same result, but yours is simpler one :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this one. In this one two inner queries are fetching starting balance and closing balance by getting minimum and maximum transact_at corresponding to a stock_id and then the parent query is combing the two queries to get starting and closing balance in an single row. I have also shared fiddle link below to try.

```
select 
  tabledata1.stock_id, 
  startBalance,
  closingBalance 
  from (
      select 
      table1.stock_id,
      balance as startBalance 
      from table1 join 
      (
          select stock_id,
          min(transact_at) as transact_at 
          from Table1 group by stock_id
      ) startTransaction 
      on Table1.stock_id = startTransaction.stock_id and 
      Table1.transact_at = startTransaction.transact_at
  ) tabledata1
  join (
    select 
    table1.stock_id,
    balance as closingBalance 
    from table1 join 
    (
      select stock_id,
      max(transact_at) as transact_at
      from Table1 group by stock_id
    ) endTransaction 
    on Table1.stock_id = endTransaction.stock_id 
    and Table1.transact_at = endTransaction.transact_at
  ) tabledata2 
  on tabledata1.stock_id = tabledata2.stock_id;
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a00161/13)

Comment: thanks @Aman Chhabra that is correct, but if theres a simplier version though

Comment: @webdev Sorry mate, this is the only one that I can think for now, but open for any suggestion or improvements in the query above.

Comment: The real problem here is that MySQL does not support analytic functions, so we're forced to write a verbose query.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I agree

Answer (score 0):

Try This One.

```
SELECT stock_id,MAX(balance) as start_balance, MIN(balance) as ending_balance  FROM tbl_balance GROUP BY stock_id
```

Comment: This one is returning min and max balance whereas the OP is asking for starting and closing balance that can be identified through date. Hope that helps.